# Cannot use SSH after one night

Tags: centos, ssh, sftp

I am using CentOS 7 server. Yesterday's night, I lean using SSH and SFTP. Everything is ok. I connect to SFTP via File Zilla on macOS 10.14.3

SFTP:

```
sftp://103.48.194.xxx
user: root
password: ****
port: 22
```

But today, I cannot use also SSH and SFTP. With SSH by macOS Terminal, I see I enter correct password, but cannot finish success

The result of `ssh -v root@103.48.194.xxx` is

```
➜  ~ ssh -v root@103.48.194.xx
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 103.48.194.xx [103.48.194.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 103.48.194.xx:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:9Ohti7PtCJAN3qMGgBiKh7oBiveKiFy9gHSOI1j3LK8
debug1: Host '103.48.194.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xpUMQMzX3z6ADCqgmrHzQ7T5GSmDAkVkFVE4aK+3Csc
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xpUMQMzX3z6ADCqgmrHzQ7T5GSmDAkVkFVE4aK+3Csc
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@103.48.194.xx's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 103.48.194.xx ([103.48.194.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Last failed login: Fri Feb 22 23:54:05 EST 2019 from 113.119.xxx.21 on ssh:notty
There were 6 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Fri Feb 22 23:38:47 2019 from 14.232.141.136
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 103.48.194.xx closed.
Transferred: sent 2532, received 2756 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 26858.7, received 29234.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Try to connect via SFTP

```
➜  source_code sftp -v root@103.48.194.xx
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 103.48.194.xx [103.48.194.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 103.48.194.xx:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:9Ohti7PtCJAN3qMGgBiKh7oBiveKiFy9gHSOI1j3LK8
debug1: Host '103.48.194.34' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xpUMQMzX3z6ADCqgmrHzQ7T5GSmDAkVkFVE4aK+3Csc
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xpUMQMzX3z6ADCqgmrHzQ7T5GSmDAkVkFVE4aK+3Csc
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/donhuvy/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@103.48.194.xx's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 103.48.194.xx ([103.48.194.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2244, received 2468 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 19786.3, received 21761.4
debug1: Exit status 1
Connection closed
```

I can still access server (root account) by web console.

I need to connect to SSH, SFTP from macOS.

Comment: Looks like root's login shell is failing (`/bin/bash: No such file or directory`)

Comment: I think may be I don't mount directory for `root` user, but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: @Kusalananda That isn't going to work. The SSH server uses the account's shell to launch any command requested by the client. If the shell isn't working, then launching commands won't work.

Comment: @Kenster Ah, that may well be true. I don't tend to delete shell binaries that are in use so I haven't run into this...